# Dynamically calculate waiting time in a queue

Tags: c#

I have a method that calculates the waiting time in a queue. It works fine for a small range. However, you can quickly see that this would become very tedious to do with a large range. In this example, if you are #1 in the queue, your wait time is 'very soon'. If it's greater than 1 and less than 5: 0 to 1 weeks, and so on... How can I loop through this list to dynamically find the place in the queue?

```
if ((PlaceInQueue) <= 1)
{
    result = "Very soon!";
}
if ((PlaceInQueue) > 1 & (PlaceInQueue) < 5)
{
    result = "From 0 to 1 weeks.";
}
if ((PlaceInQueue) >= 5 & (PlaceInQueue) < 11)
{
    result = "From 1 to 2 weeks.";
}
if ((PlaceInQueue) >= 11 & (PlaceInQueue) < 17)
{
    result = "From 2 to 3 weeks.";
}
if ((PlaceInQueue) >= 17 & (PlaceInQueue) < 23)
{
    result = "From 3 to 4 weeks.";
}
```

Here's what I've started and what I'm trying to accomplish. The first few if statements before the while loop may need to be hard coded as the math isn't exact and the rest would be dynamic. So, in this example, the results are correct up until the place in the queue is 11 or greater (inside the while loop).

```
int n = 1;                 
int max = 300; // Stop calculating when the max is reached  
var PlaceInQue = (Convert.ToInt32(placeInQueue)); // This is the position in the Que
foreach (var item in PlaceInQue)
{

    if (PlaceInQue <= 1)
    {
        result = "Very soon!";
    }

    if (PlaceInQue > 1 & PlaceInQue < 5)
    {
        result = "From 0 to 1 weeks.";
    }

    if (PlaceInQue >= 5 & PlaceInQue < 11)
    {
        result = "From 1 to 2 weeks.";
    }
    while (n < max)
    {
        if (PlaceInQue >= (should increment from 11 and then 17 then 23 then 29 and so on...) & PlaceInQue < (increment from 17 then 23 then 29 then 35 and so on...)
        {
            result = (should increment from "2 to 3 weeks" and then "3 to 4 weeks" and so on until max is reached...)
        }
        n++;
    }
}
```

Comment: @John Yes. I've corrected this. Thought that was the American version of the word queue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
if (PlaceInQue <= 1)
{
    result = "Very soon!";
}
else if (PlaceInQue < 5)
{
    result = "From 0 to 1 weeks.";
}
else if (PlaceInQue < 11)
{
    result = "From 1 to 2 weeks.";
}
else if 
{
    for (int n = 11; n <= max; n += 5)
    {
        if (PlaceInQue >= n && PlaceInQue < n + 5)
        {
            int weeks = n / 5;
            result = $"From {weeks} to {(weeks + 1)} weeks.";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for me for which I have checked the probable edge cases. Let me know if it doesn't work for you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Queue<int> queue = new Queue<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 300));
        foreach (var placeInQueue in queue)
        {
            if(placeInQueue <= 1)
                Console.WriteLine($"Place: {placeInQueue}. Very soon!");
            else if(placeInQueue < 300)
            {
                var fromTo = GetFromTo(placeInQueue);
                Console.WriteLine($"Place: {placeInQueue}. From {fromTo.Item1} to {fromTo.Item2} weeks.");
            }
        }
    }

    private static Tuple<int,int> GetFromTo(int place)
    {
        if (place < 5)
            return new Tuple<int, int>(0, 1);

        var q1 = place / 5;
        var q2 = 0;
        if((place + 1) % 6 == 0)
        {
            q2 = (place + 1) / 6;
            q1 = int.MaxValue;
        }
        else
            q2 = (place/6) == 0 ? q1 : (place/6);

        var from = Math.Min(q1, q2);
        var to = from + 1;
        return new Tuple<int, int>(from, to);
    }
}
```